# Kestrel returns 404 error with controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The code below runs directly in RoslynPad.  I'm wanting to configure Kestrel to run without appsettings.json, launchSettings.json, or IIS.  In this example http://localhost:44379 returns a 200 response.  However, http://localhost:44379/weatherforecast returns a 404 response.  How can this be modified so the controller is hit?

```
#r "nuget:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/2.2.0"
#r "nuget:Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/2.2.8"
#r "nuget:ApplicationExtensions/1.2.1"

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

Main(new string[]{});

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .ConfigureKestrel(options => {
           options.ListenLocalhost(44379);
        });


public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

       // app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        //app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}                

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var rng = new Random();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}    

public class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

    public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What version of .net core? What happens if you try to navigate to http://localhost:44379/weatherforecast/get ?

Comment: RosynPad shows I'm using .NET Core 3.1.101.  That url also returns a 404 error.

Comment: It seems like you're missing a `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();}` call

Comment: I added `services.AddMvc(setup => {
                setup.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            });` to that method.  While that sounded promising, I'm still getting the 404.